# If $f(z) = e^x \cos{y} + i e^x \sin{y}$ , then what does $f(π/4)$ equal?

Tags: complex-numbers

My attempt:

$$e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$$
$$e^x\cdot e^{iy}$$
Let $$z=x+iy$$
Then, $$e^{x+iy}=e^z$$

Thus: $$e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

This makes sense to me in some way, but we are learning about the Cauchy-Riemann Equations, so I don't see how I'm supposed to apply them here.

Comment: You are not supposed to apply them here. Hint: $\pi/4=\pi/4+i0$.

Comment: So plug in $\pi /4$ into $x$ and $0i$ into $y$. That gives me my answer above...

Comment: Plug $0$ into $y$. Right.

Comment: Ah ok, so then is my solving for $e^z$ not valid then?

Comment: You complicate it too much. :-) Since $x=\pi/4$ and $y=0$ you just have to substitute in the formula.

Comment: I always assume there is some deeper meaning to everything in life......lol! Thanks!!

Comment: $z=\frac{\pi}4$ means $x=\pi/4$, $y=0$. Since $\sin y=0,\cos y=1$ in this case, you don't need all that work (and, in fact, you are sort of assuming what is trying to be illustrated here - that $e^{z}=e^x$ when $z=x+0i$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $z=x+yi$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$:

---

So, when $z=\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}+0i$, where $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $y=0$

$$f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(0)+ie^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(0)=$$
$$f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot1+ie^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot0=$$
$$f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}+0=$$
$$f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$